# Setting a cookie to one hour lifetime

Tags: php, cookies

I am using a php script that sets the lifetime of a cookie to 1 day:

```
'cookie_lifetime' => 1
```

How can I change this to one hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your script works but this could work:

```
'cookie_lifetime' => 1/24
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this

```
setcookie("yourcookiename", $yourcookievalue, time()+3600); // 1hr = 3600 secs
```

Read more on cookies [`here`](http://php.net/setcookie) from PHP Manual.

Did you mean by `session.cookie_lifetime` ? , If so, you can set it like

```
session.cookie_lifetime 3600
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual site](https://www.php.net/setcookie)

```
 <?php
 $value = 'something from somewhere';

 setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
 setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
 setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An hour = 60sec * 60min => 3600  ;)

Lifetime is in seconds.